# Do our guardian Angels love us?

Tags: allah, malaikah, love

Salam brothers and sisters. I am aware that we have quardian angels, but I was wondering if they can develop emotions for us? Or  are they just doing the job sent by Allah and do not have any emotional attachment to us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angels love believers and they dislike sinful disbelievers.

The angels praying for believers is mentioned in the Quran. Allah says:

> It is He who confers blessing upon you, and His angels [ask Him to do so] that He may bring you out from darknesses into the light. And ever is He, to the believers, Merciful. (33:43)

The angels praying against evil people is also mentioned in the Quran. Allah says:

> Indeed, those who disbelieve and die while they are disbelievers - upon them will be the curse of Allah and of the angels and the people, all together, (2:161)

The angels praise those doing good actions in front of Allah and also pray for them:

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "(A group of) angels stay with you at night and (another group of) angels by daytime, and both groups gather at the time of the 'Asr and Fajr prayers. Then those angels who have stayed with you overnight, ascend (to Heaven) and Allah asks them (about you) ---- and He knows everything about you. "In what state did you leave My slaves?' The angels reply, 'When we left them, they were praying, and when we reached them they were praying.' " ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/56))

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "As long as any-one of you is waiting for the prayer, he is considered to be praying actually, and the angels say, 'O Allah! Be merciful to him and forgive him', (and go on saying so) unless he leaves his place of praying or passes wind (i.e. breaks his ablution). ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/40))

And the angels love people that are beloved to Allah:

> When Allah loves a servant, He calls Gabriel and says: Verily, I so and so; you should also love him, and then Gabriel begins to love him. Then he makes an announcement in the heaven saying: Allah loves so and so and you also love him, and then the inhabitants of the Heaven (the Angels) also begin to love him and then there is conferred honour upon him in the earth; and when Allah is angry with any servant He calls Gabriel and says: I am angry with such and such and you also become angry with him, and then Gabriel also becomes angry and then makes an announcement amongst the inhabitants of heaven: Verily Allah is angry with so-and so, so you also become angry with him, and thus they also become angry with him. Then he becomes the object of wrath on the earth also. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/45/201))

Angels will even intercede on the Day of Judgement for Muslims (whom they presumably loved) who were sinful causing them to temporarily enter Hell:

> The Prophet (SAW) said: When Allah has finished passing judgment among His creation, and has brought forth from the Fire those whom He wants to bring forth, Allah will command the angels and the messengers to intercede, and they will be recognized by their signs, for the Fire will consume all of the son of Adam apart from the place of prostration. Then the water of life will be poured on them, and they will grow like seeds on the banks of a rainwater stream ([Sunan An-Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai/12/112))